# $|z-1/z|=2$ where $z$ is a complex number. How to find the greatest value of $|z|$ geometrically?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> > $|z-\frac{1}{z}|=2$,
> >     where $z$ is a complex number.

How to find the greatest value of $|z|$ geometrically?

P.S: I know the algebraic method.

Tried to plot it on wolframalpha but it is treating $z$ as a real number and then plotting.

Comment: What algebraic method do you know? Please show us, because otherwise someone might spend time on doing the same thing as you already know (even though, admittedly, you explicitly ask for a geometrical method).

Comment: $|z|<=|z-4/z|+4/|z|$ which implies |z|<=2+4/|z|..solving the inequality we get $|z|<=\sqrt{5}+1$...@mickep

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310940/finding-minimum-and-maximum-value-of-complex-number

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal that's not a geometrical method.I wish to find the plot of |z-1/z|=2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A first step. You ask for what the greatest $|z|$ is, satisfying
$$
|z-1/z|=2.
$$
But you also want a picture. The $z$ that satisfy the equation are represented by two circles in the complex plane. One way of seeing this is to square, let $z=x+iy$, and simplify to conclude that
$$
\bigl((x-1)^2+y^2-2\bigr)\bigl((x+1)^2+y^2-2\bigr)=0.
$$
I include a picture below. On the other hand, that does not provide a geometrical solution to your first problem, of finding the largest $|z|$.

[image]

On the other hand, drawing also a circle with center in $(0,0)$ with radius $1+\sqrt{2}$, it will be tangent to the other circles at $x=\pm(1+\sqrt{2})$, and the other two circles will be completely inside (which is clear since the new circle has larger radius), as the second image shows. Thus, the largest value of $|z|$ is obtained when $z$ is real, and is $\pm(1+\sqrt{2})$.

[image]

Comment: I can just say beautiful.Simply beautiful :-)!!I wonder why textbooks don't provide such wonderful methods to visualize algebra :-P!!Thank you so much!But sorry our answers did'nt match! I got the max value as $1+\sqrt{5}$

Comment: @Sanchayan: Actually, you *didn't* get $1+\sqrt5$ as the maximum value for $|z|.$ Rather, you got $1+\sqrt5$ as **an** *upper bound* of $|z|.$ However, $|z|$ cannot obtain this value under the given constraints.

Comment: @CameronBuie so whats the difference between the two?Upper bound and maximum value?But my answer matches with the one in my book...i'm confused..

Comment: I have added an answer to (hopefully) clear up your confusion. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Sanchayan: I didn't add my answer as a replacement of mickep's fine answer, but rather as a supplement. Feel free to upvote mine, but mickep's is really the one that should be accepted. It is only possible to accept a single answer to each question, but you may upvote freely once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 3):

$|z|$ = $|(z+\frac{1}{z})- \frac{1}{z}| \le |(z+\frac{1}{z})|+ |\frac{1}{z}| = 2 + \frac{1}{|z|}$ which implies $|z| \le 1+\sqrt2.$ In no way it is $1+\sqrt5.$

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a geometric approach, but this is much too long for a comment (or even several comments), and I wanted to clear up [your confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437832/z-1-z-2-where-z-is-a-complex-number-how-to-find-the-greatest-value-of-z/1437862?noredirect=1#comment2930242_1437862) about my comment above. $\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}$

---

First of all, *an upper bound* on a real-valued function $f$ is a real number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\ge f(x)$ for every $x\in\dom f.$ If $\alpha>f(x)$ for all $x\in\dom f,$ we say that $\alpha$ is a *strict upper bound*. Given a real-valued function $f$ with a non-empty domain, if $f$ has an upper bound, then the set of all upper bounds of $f$ has a least element, which we call the *least upper bound* of $f$ (for obvious reasons).

For example, if we consider $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=\cos x,$ then the upper bounds of $f$ are the real numbers $\alpha\ge 1,$ the strict upper bounds of $f$ are the real numbers $\alpha>1,$ and $1$ is the least upper bound of $f.$

For another example, if we consider $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $g(x)=\arctan x,$ then the upper bounds of $g$ are the real numbers $\alpha\ge\frac\pi2,$ every upper bound of $g$ is strict, and $\frac\pi2$ is the least upper bound of $g.$

Note that $f$ actually *reaches* the least upper bound--for example, when $x=0$--but $g$ never does. When a real-valued function with an upper bound actually reaches its least upper bound, we refer to the least upper bound as the *maximum value* of $f$.

In this particular case, we are considering the function $h:A\to\Bbb R$ given by $h(z)=|z|,$ where $$A=\left\{z\in\Bbb C:\left\lvert z-z^{-1}\right\rvert=2\right\}.$$ What my comment means, then, is that $1+\sqrt5$ is a strict upper bound of $h,$ while $1+\sqrt2$ is the least upper bound (and in fact the maximum) of $h.$

---

But how can we see this? Well, the geometric approach is to note that the circle about $0$ of radius $1+\sqrt5$ doesn't intersect the set $A,$ which (as you've seen before) is:

[image]

Since you already have a geometric demonstration, here is an algebraic approach that can actually give you the maximum, and not just an upper bound.

First, observe that $$A=\left\{z\in\Bbb C:\left\lvert z-z^{-1}\right\rvert^2=4\right\}.$$ Second, observe that for all $w\in\Bbb C,$ we have $$|w|^2=w\overline{w},$$ so by properties of the modulus function, we have $$\begin{align}\left\lvert z-z^{-1}\right\rvert^2 &= \left(z-z^{-1}\right)\overline{\left(z-z^{-1}\right)}\\ &= \left(z-z^{-1}\right)\left(\overline{z}-\overline{z^{-1}}\right)\\ &= \left(z-z^{-1}\right)\left(\overline{z}-\overline{z}^{-1}\right)\\ &= z\overline z-z\overline z^{-1}-\overline z z^{-1}+z^{-1}\overline z^{-1}\\ &= z\overline z-z\overline z^{-1}-\overline{\overline z z^{-1}}+\left(z\overline z\right)^{-1}\\ &= \lvert z\rvert^2-2\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)+\left(|z|^2\right)^{-1}\end{align}$$ for all non-zero $z\in\Bbb C.$ For $z\in A,$ this becomes $$4=\lvert z\rvert^2-2\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)+\left(|z|^2\right)^{-1}.\tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$ Equivalently, $$0=\lvert z\rvert^2-4-2\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)+\left(|z|^2\right)^{-1},$$ so multiplying by $|z|^2$ yields $$0=\lvert z\rvert^4-\left(4+2\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)\right)|z|^2+1$$ for all $z\in A.$ Making the substitution $u=|z|^2$ gives us $$0=u^2-\left(4+2\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)\right)u+1\tag{$\star$}$$ for all $z\in A,$ and since the modulus function is non-negative, then maximizing $|z|$ on $A$ is equivalent to maximizing $u$ on $A.$ Applying the quadratic formula to $(\star)$ yields $$\begin{align}u &= \frac12\left(4+2\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(4+2\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)\right)^2-4}\right)\\ &= 2+\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(2+\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)\right)^2-1}\end{align}$$ for all $z\in A,$ and since we wish to *maximize* the value of $u$ on $A$ then this is equivalent to maximizing the function $$z\mapsto 2+\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)+\sqrt{\left(2+\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)\right)^2-1}$$ on $A,$ which is equivalent to maximizing $$w(z)=\re\left(z\overline z^{-1}\right)$$ on $A.$

Now, observe that $$z\overline{z}^{-1} = z\left(\frac{|z|^2}{z}\right)^{-1} = \left(\frac{z}{|z|}\right)^2 = \frac1{|z|^2}(\re z+i\im z)^2 = \frac{(\re z)^2-(\im z)^2+2i(\re z)(\im z)}{|z|^2},$$ so since $|z|^2=(\re z)^2+(\im z)^2,$ then $$w(z)=\frac{(\re z)^2-(\im z)^2}{(\re z)^2+(\im z)^2},\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ so it's enough to maximize $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2},$ where $x=\re z$ and $y=\im z$. Observe that for a fixed, non-zero $x$ value, increasing $|y|$ yields a greater denominator and a smaller numerator, so a smaller quotient! Similarly, for a fixed, non-zero $x$ value, decreasing $|y|$ yields a smaller quotient. Hence, for a fixed, non-zero $x$ value, $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is maximized when $y=0,$ in which case $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1.$ On the other hand, for $x=0$ and $y\ne0,$ we have$\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=-1,$ and so $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is maximized exactly when $x\ne 0$ and $y=0.$

Translating this back into terms of $(\heartsuit),$ we have that $w(z)$ is maximized when $\re z\ne 0$ and $\im z=0.$ In other words, we obtain the desired maximum when $z$ is real, or equivalently $\overline z=z.$ By $(\diamondsuit),$ $z$ maximizes $w(z)$ on $A$ if and only if $z$ is real and $$4=\lvert z\rvert^2-2\re\left(zz^{-1}\right)+\left(|z|^2\right)^{-1}=\lvert z\rvert^2-2+\left(|z|^2\right)^{-1}=\lvert z\rvert^2-2+\left(|z|^{-1}\right)^2,$$ meaning $z$ is real and $$4=\left(z-z^{-1}\right)^2.$$ Hence, either $z-z^{-1}=2$ or $z-z^{-1}=-2$ (with $z$ real) will provide the desired maximum value of $w(z)$ on $A,$ and so provide the desired maximum value of $|z|$ on $A.$ The only possible solutions $z,$ then, are $\pm(1+\sqrt2)$ and $\pm(\sqrt2-1).$ The first two provide the maximum value: $1+\sqrt2.$

My, wasn't that a pain? The geometric solution looks even better now, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for:
$$|z-\frac{1}{z}|=2$$
If we multiply by $|z|$:
$$|z^2-1^2|=2|z|$$
This equation resembles the form of an [hyperbola](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/hyperbola/graph-equation-of-a-hyperbola.php)
$$x^2-y^2=c^2$$